# port's owner switched in netstat after killing the process

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, socket

I had a connection established between two processes:

```
netstat -tpn | grep 9999
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:*58728*         127.0.0.1:9999          ESTABLISHED 17366/*my_app.bin*
```

After killing this process,
1. The connection is still in `ESTABLISHED` state
2.  I've noticed port `58728` is still in the netstat table, with another process name:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:*58728*         127.0.0.1:9999          ESTABLISHED 19645/*udhcpc*
```

How could it be?

Comment: I would assume that the connection is not *still* there but *again*. Does the "new" process exist already when you kill the "old" one? Save the putput of `ps -e -o pid,euser,time,etime,args` before killing `my_app.bin`. The "new" process may have been waiting for the port to become free all the time.

Comment: Yes, it's exists before killing the process. It's kind of DHCP daemon. I'll try what you suggested. Thanks

Comment: Before killing your process you should be able to see with `strace` that the other one regularly tries to bind to this port.

Comment: @HaukeLaging ok, this is REALLY strange. When I did what you suggested `./strace /sbin/udhcpc -R --foreground -p /var/run/udhcpc.eth0.pid -i eth0` then `udhcpc` doesn't behaves the same! All ports that were before captured by `udhcpc` are now just `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:48222         127.0.0.1:9999          TIME_WAIT   -` Which is what was supposed to happen in the first place!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't accurate.  
When the `udhcpc` father is the `init`, then `udhcpc` always hijacks the released ports.  
When I start `udhcpc` with `strace`, or another intermediate app/script (so `init` isn't the father), the `udhcpc` doesn't/can't hijack the released ports.  
I don't understand:  
1. What it this behaviour?  
2. Why would `udhcpc` hijack ports? Is it malware or what?

Comment: But now another application catches the port. If I start `udhcpc` with `bash`. Now I sometimes see `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44428         127.0.0.1:9999          ESTABLISHED 10045/bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem was the `udhcpc` process was spawned from my `my_app.bin` process.
In this spawn the spawned process inherites all the open file descriptors of `my_app.bin`. So when I close the socket from `my_app.bin`, it's not being closed from `udhcpc`.

Solutions:

1. Use `O_CLOEXEC` when opening a socket, or `fcntl()` with `FD_CLOEXEC` flag later.
2. In the spawed process, close all not-relevant open file descriptors.

In my case I don't control `udhcpc`, so I need to use option number `1`.